why is "ng --open serve" not working in my terminal when i am trying to run the angular app
what it is showing me
so I want to launch my angular app and I have to input some things in my vs code terminal. I inputted "ng --open serve" but it tells me that "ng cannot be loaded because running scripts are unavailable". I don't even know what that means. so my app is not going to work or display.
I tried changing it around e.g. "ng serve --open", I tried reloading vs code, and i tried changing my profile.

Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? Please read the error message before you ask a question. It contains a link to the answer.

Unfortunately, PowerShell defaults to preventing execution of script files (*.ps1) in workstation editions of Windows, necessitating a change in execution policy first, such as with Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser -Force
See the linked documentation and duplicate for details (note that the question there is about a slightly different scenario, but the answers cover the basics).

This may be caused by script execution being restricted on your development machine. You can try updating the execution policy in PowerShell to allow the execution of local scripts.

Right-click on the Start menu and select Windows PowerShell (Admin).
Run this command to change the execution policy Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
Restart VSCode
Run your angular start command ng serve --open

-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned sets the execution policy to allow the execution of locally created scripts, but requires digital signatures for scripts downloaded from the internet.

Helpful, but note that running elevated, i.e. with administrative privileges is not required with -Scope CurrentUser (it only is with the default scope, -Scope LocalMachine). As an aside: Your method for starting an elevated PowerShell session doesn't seem to work in Windows 11 anymore (no PowerShell-related commands in the menu).
